# Best architectural choice to merge 2 Spring Data JPA repository classes

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am pretty new in **Spring Data JPA** and I have the following doubt about the best way to implement the following situation:

So basically I have the following 2 model classes:

**Room** (representing a room of an accomodation):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "room")
public class Room implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_accomodation_fk", nullable = false)
    private Accomodation accomodation;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_room_tipology_fk", nullable = false)
    private RoomTipology roomTipology;

    @Column(name = "room_number")
    private String number;

    @Column(name = "room_name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "room_description")
    @Type(type="text")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "max_people")
    private Integer maxPeople;

    @Column(name = "is_enabled")
    private Boolean isEnabled;

    public Room() {
    }

    // GETTER AND SETTER METHODS
}
```

And **RoomTipology** that represent a tipology of room  (something like: single room, double bed room, etcetc):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "room_tipology")
public class RoomTipology implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "tipology_name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "tipology_description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "time_stamp")
    private Date timeStamp;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "roomTipology")
    private List<Room> rooms;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "roomTipology")
    private RoomRate roomRate;

    // GETTER AND SETTER METHODS
}
```

Ok, using Spring Data JPA I will have 2 different repository classes (one for the **Room** entity class and another one for the **RoomTipology** entity class, something like this:

```
@Repository
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
public interface RoomDAO extends JpaRepository<Room, Long> {

   //@Query("FROM Room WHERE accomodation = :id")
   List<Room> findByAccomodation(Accomodation accomodation);

}

@Repository
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
public interface RoomTipologyDAO extends JpaRepository<RoomTipologyDAO , Long> {

   // METHOD RELATED TO THE ACCESS TO ROOM TIPOLOGY ENTITIES

}
```

Ok, I have the following architectural doubt:

I have 2 little repositories classes that access to something that are semantically similar (the room concept and the room tipology concept are both related to the room).

Furthermore, as you can see in the code of the **RoomTipology** entity class there is the following field:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "roomTipology")
private List<Room> rooms;
```

that is mapped by the **@OneToMany** annotation (because starting from a specific room tipology I want to access to all the room of this accomodation of this tipology: all the single bed room or all the double bed room and so on...).

So, following this architectural style, I will have the method that return the **List** associated to a room tipology into the **RoomTipologyDAO** repository class and not into the **RoomTipology** repository class..it works fine but it is semantically bad because I will have a method of **RoomTipologyDAO** that doesn't return something related to **RoomTipology** instance but a list of **Room** object.

Is it not nasty?

So what is the best way to create an architecture that uses **Spring Data JPA** in this case?

I can't not do something like:

```
public interface RoomDAO extends JpaRepository<Room, Long> extends JpaRepository<RoomTipology, Long> {
    ........................................................
    ........................................................
    ........................................................
}
```

because Java doesn't support multiple heredity, but I think that the best choice should obtain something like this.

Maybe can I create something like a **RoomMetaDAO** class that have the **RoomDAO** and the **RoomTipologyDAO** as field? Can it work?

What do you think could be the best architectural choice for my situation?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong here. No need to mess with the repository like that, keep it simple and keep them separate, just for one entity at the time, else it gets confusing if you would rather use them in other relationships in future. Also use Set instead of List if you don't plan to order them.

Comment: *I will have the method that return the List associated to a room tipology into the RoomTipologyDAO repository*: why would you do that? If you really need that method (instead of just getting the typology and calling getRooms()), put it in RoomDAO.findByTopology().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are absolutely correct in being sceptical about this.

The mistake is to assume that you should have one repository per entity. Instead you should look into the concept of aggregate roots from domain driven design.

An aggregate root is an entity that is used to manipulate a bunch of entities that can only accessed and modified through the aggregate root.

You want one repository per such aggregate root, which would be in your case the Room.

This is explained in much more detail in [this article](http://static.olivergierke.de/lectures/ddd-and-spring/) by Oliver Gierke, lead of the Spring Data project.

Comment: Tnx so much, this is absolutly what I need. Do you have also some code example?